# How to expose DomU's to router network?

Tags: linux, networking, xen

I currently have a server connected to a router through a single NIC. The server has a running XEN setup with several DomU's. Everything seems to work fine, I can access internet from both Dom0 and all of the DomU's. The problem is, I want to be able to access DomU's from other server's while now I can only access DomU's from Dom0 and DomU's on the same server.

Iv'e searched all over for answers (probably not hard enough but I've tried my best) but was unable to find anything pointing me the right direction.

So could anyone here explain me, how do you make your DomU instances appear on the same network as your Dom0 or any other server attached to my router? I access my server (Dom0 in this case) using 10.0.0.100 and would like to be able to ssh into DomU instances of this particular server using 10.0.0.101, 10.0.0.102, etc.

Similarly how VirtualBox bridged network allows me to access my VM's using a bridged network from any other machine on the same network by assigning it an IP from my router.

P.S.: here's my current [ifconfig](http://pastebin.com/AXWQEkw7), [bridges](http://pastebin.com/std4iiYw) and [VMs](http://pastebin.com/MBwhv4Bw)

Comment: looks like you want to use bridged networking. Have a look here : http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Networking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your Dom0 physical interface (`eth0`) into the same bridge (`br0`) as your virtual interfaces (`vifX.Y`).

The bridge then functions as a layer 2 switch, connecting your VMs to the physical network.

You'll also need to take the Dom0's IP address off the physical interface and place it on the bridge. The physical interface won't have an IP address anymore, it's a "bridge slave" now.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to check your suggestion earlier as I didn't have the access to the server but it seems you are correct. I added eth0 to br0 and eureka, everything worked, almost. I also had to assign IP directly to br0 and drop it from eth0 to get access to dom0, but nevertheless thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: That's why I said "IP address then goes on the bridge, not on the physical interface" :)

Comment: For some reason, I assumed that it would reassign it to br0 automatically :)

Comment: Ah, I see! I will edit my answer so it's a bit clearer for others facing the same problem who find this. Thank you for explaining :)